# Ubuntu 14.04 Wi-Fi will not connect dual boot

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot

I am new to Ubuntu and today I dual booted my laptop with Windows and Ubuntu 14.04. It will not let me connect to Wi-Fi for some reason saying "no network devices available" and I have no access to Ethernet. I have searched the web and everywhere said I have to be connected to Ethernet to download the driver required. I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Please run [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/380067) and post the output file to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) (I guess you'll have to do that from Windows).

Comment: What specific wireless card are you using? To find out, boot into Windows, search for "Device Manager" in the start menu, and then find you card. Without this info, it is hard to give you advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do: download the driver package manually using Windows (it might be a good idea to put it on a USB drive, because you may be currently unable to access the HDD from Ubuntu). Then manually install the package in Ubuntu.

Comment: You might be a bit more descriptive on what package and how to install it when it can be accessed from Ubuntu.

Comment: @Anders I couldn't be specific because the OP didn't tell what specific wifi adapter he was using.

Comment: Then I might suggest ask the OP about that, explain how to obtain it and then explain that the answers is only as good as the information in the question.  Yes, it is good that you answer.